# Fixed effect regression with clustered standard errors

Tags: r, plm

I'm currently working on a fixed effects regression in r.

I have a dataset consisting of the following variables: total compensation of the CEO of a firm `(TOTAL_COMP)`, the firm code `(GVKEY)`, the fiscal year `(FISCAL_YEAR)`, a number of firm characteristics (like assets `(AT)`) and the industry of the firm `(SIC)`.

Although the data is proprietary it looks like:

e.g.

```
TOTAL_COMP <- c(100, 200, 50, 150, 300, 200, 150, 75)

GVKEY <- c("103", "103", "103", "103", "104", "104", "104", "104")

AT <- c(1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2300)

FISCAL_YEAR <- c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)

SIC <- c(78, 78, 78, 78, 80, 80, 80, 80)
```

I used the `plm function` and ran a fixed effects regression with industry `(SIC)` fixed effects.

```
model <- plm(TOTAL_COMP ~ AT, index = "SIC", model = "within", data = COMBINED_DATA)
```

I subsequently want to cluster the standard errors at the firm `(GVKEY)` and not the industry `(SIC)` level. I am, however, not sure which function to use. I tried:

```
coeftest(model, vcov = vcovHC(regression, type = "HC0", cluster = "group"))
```

but am afraid that this clusters the standard errors at the industry `(SIC)` instead of the firm `(GVKEY)` level. How do I compute the standard errors at the firm `(GVKEY)` level?

(packages used: `plm` and `lmtest`)

Comment: I would recommend looking at the `fixest` package. You can read about clustering standard errors [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/vignettes/standard_errors.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `SIC` as dummy variable and cluster the standard errors at the firm level:

```
# The fixed effects model
model <- lm(TOTAL_COMP ~ AT + factor(SIC), data = COMBINED_DATA)

# The fixed effects model with cluster settings
library(estimatr)
Clu_robust <- lm_robust(TOTAL_COMP ~ AT + factor(SIC), 
                        data = COMBINED_DATA,
                        clusters = GVKEY, 
                        se_type = 'stata')
```